# ¿Cómo puedo emplear ng-repeat y solo mostrar la primera opción, o las primeras dos opciones?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quisiera saber como utilizar un **ng-repeat** pero solo quiero mostrar la primera opción, las demás opciones van a depender de un botón.

Quiero que se visualice la primera opción, el primer **select** y el input numérico, las demás opciones se van a visualizar al darle click al botón.

PD: El botón va a aparecer hasta que ya no haya más opciones que seleccionar.

Comment: `|limitTo:1` dentro del `ng-repeat` el número se puede modificar a la cantidad que desee.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más fácil es usando el filtro **limitTo**, seria algo como:

```
<div ng-repeat="opt in options | limitTo:1"></div>
```